# django tinymce javascript not loading on non-admin pages

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce

Im trying to implement TinyMCE on Django, i have successfully implement it on admin page using settings like this :

admin.py:

```
class TinyMCEAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
            js = ('/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', '/media/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',)
```

settings.py :

```
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = '/media/js/tiny_mce/'
TINYMCE_JS_URL = '/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
```

then when i try to implement it on my form(non-admin) :

forms.py:

```
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class Foo(forms.Form):
    title       = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content     = forms.CharField(widget = TinyMCE())
```

When i see the result, it just showing plain html textarea, then i hit "F12" on Chrome, then it says : 'Uncaught reference error: tinyMCE is not defined'.

How do i fix that error? thx guys

Answer (score 4):

[Looking at the documentation](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#templates), if you are using TinyMCE in your form outside of the admin, you need to tell it to include the JS/CSS required to render TinyMCE manually. So in your base template (or somewhere similar) you need to add:

```
<head>
    ...
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
```

or you could simply manually load the js:

```
<head>
   <script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
   <script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/textareas.js"></script>
</head>
```

but the former is probably easier

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file `tiny_mce.js` has not been loaded in this case.